# Using a BST to find a query based on some property

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

If I have a list of tuples:
[(2021/4/1, 10), (2021/1/2, 30), ..., (2021/2/1, 25)]

How do I returned the maximum element after some given date? I'm having lots of trouble on this problem. My first though is to use a BST, I'm not sure how it will help yet, but I believe the idea is related to successor. I'm stuck! The goal for me would be log n time.

Comment: The elements of the list are sorted according to the date?

Comment: @zois No, they are not sorted and they're not unique either.

Comment: Updated after @LetmeKnow update

Comment: Finding a max among unsorted elements is O(n), is there a reason you aim for O(logn)?

Comment: This is a homework problem that said `log n` is best but there's no answer key, unfortunately.

Comment: If its unordered you hat to read at least the input once. That takes O(n) time -> There couldn't be an algorithm faster than O(n).